# Chrome extension that searches for text in a page then changes the message on the popup as a result

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a project where my goal is to have a chrome extension that looks for words on a page, then displays a popup with a message that depends on whether it finds that word (or words). I'm not very experienced in JavaScript + HTML, but I've been trying my best. At the moment, the extension does have a pop-up, but it doesn't change the text of the pop-up. I can't tell if it's an issue with it searching the page or taking the results of the search and updating (or both). I'm working in manifest v3.

My manifest looks like this

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "description": "searches for keywords to provide product safety information",
    "content_scripts":[{
      "matches":["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
      "js":["search.js","popup.js"]
    }]
}
```

This is the html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Baby Safety Extension</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Baby Safety Extension</h1>
    <p id="product">We could not determine the type of product.</p>
    <script src="popup.js">whichproduct();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've tried to create to search the page (search.js). I would definitely not be surprised if this was wrong, but it's what I had put together based on the chrome examples

```
//creates a variable that selects the body of the page
const body = document.querySelector("body");
//if a body exists, checks to see if certain elements exist in the body, sets their corresponding variables to true if they do
if (body) {
    var text = body.textContent;
    var bouncer = text.includes("bouncer" || "Bouncer");
}
```

And this is my whichproduct function in popup.js

```
function whichproduct(){
    if (bouncer === true){
        document.getElementById("product")=("You're looking at a bouncer. Here's some tips for using a bouncer safely");
      }
}
```

Does anyone have tips about where my code is going wrong or where I could find additional documentation about some of these functions? Thanks so much for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extension is half wrong.
I have fixed it.

manifest.json
**Note**: <all_urls> should be changed to suit your purposes.

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Baby Safety Extension</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Baby Safety Extension</h1>
  <p id="product">We could not determine the type of product.</p>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const search = () => {
  const text = document.body.textContent;
  const bouncer = text.includes("bouncer" || "Bouncer");

  return bouncer;
}

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
    func: search
  }, (result) => {
    if (result[0].result) {
      const whichproduct = "You're looking at a bouncer. Here's some tips for using a bouncer safely";
      document.getElementById("product").innerText = whichproduct;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help! I uploaded those changes and it's mostly fixed the issues, however chrome is giving me an error in the popup.js. It says it can't read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript'). Do you happen to know how I could fix that? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Have you replaced manifest.json?

Comment: Yes, I did, and after uninstalling and reuploading the extension, it got rid of the error. Thanks again so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = ...` instead of `document.getElementById("product") = ...`.

At least this is what I believe you are doing wrong.